# How to use table name inside a trigger code as a variable? MySQL/MariaDB

Tags: mysql, variables, triggers, reference, mariadb

How to reference the table triggered inside the trigger code without knowing the table name? And by that I mean that I need to get that code and paste it into 20 triggers, each for a different table. :-/

```
CREATE TRIGGER register_eventLog_for_table_xyz
AFTER UPDATE ON xyz
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
     CALL reg_event(@this_tableName, dataChanged);
END
```

Comment: I'm not aware of any function within mysql that would return either the running stored procedure's name or the name of the table the trigger is attached to. You need to hard code the table name into the parameter.

Comment: Maybe I was dreaming but I remember to see it somewhere on the Internet but I can't remember what was the site.

Comment: Your application could initialise a mysql user variable using SET statement to store the table name there and your trigger could use the same variable to set the table name. I cannot really think of anything else atm.

Answer (score 0):

Build a script to look into `information_schema.TABLES` to find the list of tables and create a `TRIGGER` for each table.  It would also build the string for the tablename.